# Element vs. Generic Type <T>

Tags: swift

I wonder why Swift uses `Element` rather than `Generic <T>` in the following example.

What is the difference between `Element` vs `T`

[image]

Comment: You can name the generic placeholder whatever you like ... `T`, `Element`, `Rumpelstilzchen` , it makes no difference.

Comment: @MartinR, why swift uses as `Element` rather than using commonly used name `T` instead?

Comment: @hotspring it is for readability. `Element` is far more understandable than `T` in case of a collection or array

Comment: When you say "commonly used name `T`" that's from a very specific set of languages (typically ones derived from Java or C++). The "commonly used name" for a generic type in the ML (and later Haskell) world is `a`, and in Scala it's `A`. Swift's approach is no more unusual than `T`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html):

> **Type Parameters**
>
> Type parameters specify and name a placeholder type, and are written immediately after the function’s name, between a pair of matching angle brackets (such as `<T>`).
>
> **Naming Type Parameters**
>
> In most cases, type parameters have descriptive names, such as Key and Value in `Dictionary<Key, Value>` and Element in `Array<Element>`, which tells the reader about the relationship between the type parameter and the generic type or function it’s used in. However, when there isn’t a meaningful relationship between them, it’s traditional to name them using single letters such as T, U, and V, such as T in the `swapTwoValues(_:_:)` function above.

So

```
func createArray<Element>(element: Element) -> [Element] { ... }
func createArray<T>(element: T) -> [T] { ... }
func createArray<Rumpelstilzchen>(element: Rumpelstilzchen) -> [Rumpelstilzchen] { ... }
```

are identical functions. Here the placeholder type is the element type of the returned array, therefore `Element` is a suitable “descriptive name.”

But it makes no difference otherwise, is it up to you to choose a name for the placeholder, balancing between readability and conciseness.

Answer (score 2):

`T` is not particularly traditional. In FP, Backus uses `T`, but ML, from around the same time, uses `a`. Haskell uses `a`, Scala uses `A`. There's a mix of choices.

Swift, however, has strong reasons to use descriptive names. First, it's a quite descriptive language. Types are named with fully spelled-out words. Methods typically are literate in construction. Variables and properties are rarely abbreviated. There's no reason that type parameters should be uniquely obscure.

It also matches well with associated types which are quite naturally verbose. What would you call Collection's index type besides `Index`? Why should its "element" type be specially abbreviated? And if Array implements Collection, why should it create a distinct name (T) that it would then have to associate with Collection's Element? Why would you special-case all this just to make the type name unintuitive?

The deeper question would be, why *wouldn't* Array's element be called Element?